# PHP фильтры $_REQUEST

Tags: php, уязвимости

```
$a = "123";
$get = $_REQUEST['a'];
echo "test ".$get.".gif";
```

Почему вместо `$get` нельзя выполнить `php` код? Фильтров нет, но кавычки отображаются как текст. Если в `$get` задать - `$a` или `".$a."`, то выведет так, как прописано. Хотя по идее, кавычки должны закрыть. Как закрыть кавычку от `echo`?
Почему я не могу сделать так:

```
echo "test var"; //.gif";
```

То есть, закрыть вывод `echo` и остальную часть строки закомментировать //

Comment: про кавычки опять непонятно. под "кавычками" имеются в виду теги РНР?

Comment: Поясните вопрос. Предоставьте вывод.

Comment: Если в $get задать - $a или ".$a.", то выведет так, как прописано. Хотя по идее кавычки должны закрыть.

Comment: Не понял вашего вопроса. У меня вывело `test .gif`

Answer (score 0):

Команда echo не исполняет PHP код.

Comment: Что за бред? Я вообще спрашивал вот что:  Как закрыть кавычку от echo?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "test var"; //.gif"; выведет test var

echo "test var"; //.gif""; выведет test var
```

Все что после двойного слеша это комментарий а в данном случае коментарий есть но не имеет не одного символа тк интерпритатор дымает код закончился после ?>:

```
echo "test var"; //?> .gif" выведет test var .gif"
```

.gif" - это уже не PHP код

ЗАКРОЙТЕ КАВЫЧКУ ТАК:

```
echo "test var"; //" выведет test var

echo "test var"; #" выведет test var

echo "test var"; /*"*/ выведет test var
```

Я обычно конкатенирую (да и вообще привык php использовать одинарные кавычки)

```
echo 'test '.$get.'.gif';
```

С двойными это не обязательно:

```
echo "test $get.gif";
```

если понадобится можно явно указать границы переменной:

```
echo "test {$get}.gif";
```

или

```
echo "test ${get}.gif";
```

Comment: Я тоже так думал, но почему если в $_REQUEST['a'] подать ".$a.", то выводит: test ".$a.".gif так строку как текст? А должно быть: test 123.gif

Comment: Данная строчка: $_REQUEST['a'] = ".$a."; присвоит элементу массива строку: точка+значение переменной а+точка. Покажите ваш код хотя бы несколько строк. Ваш верхний код не совсем понятен. $a = "123";
$get = $_REQUEST['a']; - есть ли значение в элементе массива?
echo "test ".$get.".gif";

Comment: Смысл будет так, но я не уверен что это вам нужно $a = "123";
$_REQUEST['a'] = $a;
$get = $_REQUEST['a'];
echo "test ".$get.".gif";